# Too many declined flags to flag post

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, flag-ban

So I've been lurking on the First Post queue, and as such have been flagging some dodgy posts. I go to flag [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5474181) as 'Not an Answer' and I can't because 'Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!'.

I've had one flag declined today, and another 2 declined 5 days ago. I might add that on one of these I flagged as off topic and was declined, but the question was closed as too-broad and the other just posted a stack-trace with no problem-description (hence flagged as off-topic) and was declined.

Meanwhile I've just hit 200 helpful flags, on my profile and had 4 of the 10 flags I've raised in the past 2 hours accepted.

Is this right? 3 declined flags in under a week and I'm banned from flagging posts? I don't think I'm an overzealous flagger, but maybe I'm wrong.

EDIT: My ban has been lifted, but I still disagree with some of these declined flags.

Comment: Moderators cannot lift that ban. It is automated based on the number of declined flags you've had in the past however many days or something. I forget the exact criteria. Likely one of your other flags got deemed helpful and offset your decline ratio.

Comment: That seems right. One of my flags from earlier was helpful. I still disagree with some of the declined's that I got. Especially the [giant stack-trace question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402723/org-hibernate-exception-dataexception-could-not-execute-jdbc-batch-update) one.

Comment: I only have two declined and I'm banned for now as well.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Since last 7 days I've 4 helpful flags, 1 declined and 1 disputed, and I've been banned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 3 declined flags in under a week and I'm banned from flagging posts?

Yes, this is possible. The automatic ban formula looks at your flags of past 7 days. In case you flagged 10 posts and 3 were declined (more than 25%), the ban kicks in. Note: the automated scripts may not have accounted your flags which were raised today.

Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/

Comment: @JamesMassey good to know that the ban has been lifted. Regarding your comment about disagreement on declined flags, the general community consensus is that there are too many flags to handle and moderators being humans are prone to mistakes. Don't sweat much over it.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm, I just got the same message. I have flagged 6 within the past week and one was deemed " declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". Then 17 days before that, with no flags in between, I had another flagged "not constructive". So it seems the algorithm is a little off unless the script isn't looking at flags over the past 24 hours.

If that is the case then I had one flag in the past week and it was declined, making my rate 100%...but I was able to flag some within the past 24 hours.

Comment: [Unless I read his answer wrong, Shog said this formula did change a bit recently.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243601/266735)