# How should I report suspected voting irregularities?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

I received a bunch of downvotes within a few minutes, one on each of several recent answers I've made in the [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937539/parse-tab-separated-text-file-in-google-sheets/26948108#26948108), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521772/typeerror-in-google-form-script/26937826#26937826), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815406/trigger-in-google-form-submit-does-not-work-properly/26937696#26937696) and [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925283/how-do-i-get-add-and-sum-by-column-index-value-in-google-spreasheet/26942156#26942156).

IMHO the answers were helpful. Admittedly, they did not always give the OP exactly what they wanted (e.g. you can't do that, but here's a way to get the same result...).

I flagged the answers for moderator attention, asking that they be examined for irregularities. (My guess is that all were downvoted by a single user, without regard to the content. )

Those flags were denied, with the comment `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`.

Ok, so if flagging isn't the way to raise the concern, what is? Is there any way to get suspicious down-votes looked at? Who would be able to determine whether someone was maliciously down-voting multiple users' answers? Was this 'punishment' from a user unhappy that I down-voted one of their questions or answers? (I often add comments to explain how a question could be improved, then remove my down-vote if the OP acts on it.)

I expect that one response will be "don't worry about it, upvotes will cancel them out, for good answers." In a busy tag, that would be true. But for this tag, for whatever reason, there is very little up/down voting of answers, and many helpful, accepted answers never get an upvote at all, because so many of the posters never earn the privilege.

<sup><sub>Moments later, the two specific answers I flagged got up-voted - was that by the moderator, because I asked them to look? If so - thanks, but I'm still [barred from flagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267870/too-many-declined-flags-to-flag-post) now.</sub></sup>

Comment: Remember that even moderators can't see _who_ voted for what. Best best might be the "contact us" link.

Comment: Did this *just* happen? You need to wait for the vote-checker script to run; at least 24 hours. 4 answers probably isn't enough to be considered "serial-down voting" anyways.

Comment: A moderator cannot intervene here; only the automatic serial voting script can.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, or a developer, but they have to be _very_ inclined to step in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Manual intervention is a possibility, and it does happen, but only when the automated tools fail.  There are however times where the automated tools do fail, and mods have tools to address such situations.

Comment: @gunr2171: the option is rarely, if ever, offered.

Comment: @Servy: if there is a pattern of serial voting not caught by the script (usually because someone is voting over extended periods of time) moderators have tools to detect voting patterns between accounts, yes, and can intervene. But the pattern has to be above a threshold, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There are restrictions on when they can and can't intervene, that is correct, and the voting information is aggregated to obfuscate and anonymize the votes cast.  The point is simply that mods to intervene in these types of cases; it's not left entirely up to the automated script, even though that is the primary line of defense.

Comment: This was my mistake. When I declined the flags, it was with the idea that the when the votes were invalidated all would be well (since it was < 5 votes). I should have marked your flags as helpful. At this point, the 4 down votes against your account have been invalidated and action has been taken against the voter. Sorry for this. (PS/disclosure - I up voted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26937826) when handling the flags.)

Comment: @0x7fffffff - thanks for the info, and for your work as a moderator; I appreciate it. I see `Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!` when I open the flagging dialog now, but otherwise it appears that all is well with the world.